# Makefile tabs when I have spaces in .vimrc

Tags: linux, unix, vim, makefile

So in my .vimrc file, I have my tabs set to 2 spaces. I know that the Makefile doesn't like this and what I have been doing is temporarily deleting the .vimrc conditions I have and editing the Makefile and then adding everything back to the .vimrc file.
Is there any way I can use vim on the Makefile edit it without having to do all the changes?
My Makefiles are very simple. Like here below

```
all: main.cpp
  g++ -g -Wall main.cpp
```

Here is my .vimrc

```
set number
colorscheme ron 
set expandtab
: filetype on
: syntax on
: filetype indent on
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
```

Comment: It converts the tabs to spaces, Sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: I think adding an [autocmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) looks promising. Especially intercepting the [BufWritePost](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWritePost) event.

Comment: @programmer1010 did you use any of the answers?  Some are ambiguous to me so I was wondering how you proceeded.  Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 8):

You're missing out on Vim's [`:help filetype-plugin`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_43.txt.html#filetype-plugin) functionality. If you put

```
:filetype plugin on
```

(you can combine all filetype commands from your `~/.vimrc` as one `:filetype indent plugin on`), and assuming your Makefile has a regular name so that it is detected (or you manually `:setfiletype make`), this will load buffer-local settings from `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/make.vim`, which contains these indent settings:

```
" Make sure a hard tab is used, required for most make programs
setlocal noexpandtab softtabstop=0
```

If you explicitly don't want the filetype plugin feature (but be aware that any built-in option can be tweaked via user-configuration ([`:help after-directory`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#after-directory)), and the defaults are useful in general), you could emulate this setting via `:autocmd` in your `~/.vimrc`, too:

```
autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab softtabstop=0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that setting your editor properly is the correct answer.  However I'll just point out that if you use GNU make 3.82 or higher you could change the recipe introduction character from a TAB to something else using [.RECIPEPREFIX](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-_002eRECIPEPREFIX-_0028change-the-recipe-prefix-character_0029) as in:

```
.RECIPEPREFIX = |

all: main.cpp
| g++ -g -Wall main.cpp
```

As per the docs the prefix must be a single character, it cannot be a string.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a vim modeline to your Makefile, either as first or last line, to set the `noexpandtab` option on a per-file basis:

```
# vim: set noexpandtab:
```

Comment: What would that accomplish?  I don't understand how this answers the question.  More details would be helpful.

Comment: In vim type `:help modeline` and read the documentation about modelines. You'll probably understand how this answers your question.

Comment: Sure but I shouldn't have to do that.  An answer shouldn't be that ambiguous and should include that type of detail.

Comment: I believe a 1-3 sentence summary of the modline would really improve this answer.